# What happened to signwizard in signtool of Windows SDK 7.0?

Tags: winapi, codesign, authenticode, signtool

I'm looking for the convenient signwizard in signtool.exe but cannot find it anymore in the Windows SDK 7.0.
Is it in a separate tool now or is there only the CLI left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find an [answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387764(VS.85).aspx) in the latest version of the MSDN

> signwizard: This command is not supported.
>
> **Windows Vista and earlier**:  Launches
>   the signing wizard. Only a single file
>   can be specified for the file name
>   command-line parameter.

As I understand, it means that the parameter no more exists in the Windows SDK 7.0.

Comment: I didn't have this comment when I last checked on MSDN. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Well that's quite unfortunate. It was a very useful feature. Has it been replaced by something similar?

Comment: Microsoft... always known for removing useful features... @JamesCameron: Is this tool open source? I can't find any additional info. I personally wouldn't trust a closed source tool for this special job.

Comment: @StanE: Actually i wrote it. Its written using AutoIt and can easily be decompiled, its pretty small.

Comment: @JamesCameron I'm sorry. I didn't wanted to sound rude. Thank you for your tool! I will try it out. I have now studied the MS documentation and I saw that the command line signtool is quite easy to use. I integrated it into my tool-chain to sign my compiled applications automatically.

Answer (score -1):

It is still absent in Windows SDK 7.0A RC. You can try download an older version of .Net SDK (or Windows SDK if it includes .Net SDK).